# Some kind of Event scoping in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, events

I'm running in asp.net with javascript and jquery. I've got some javascript that runs on document ready that uses jquery to assign some onclick events with the .on function. That's fine. I also have a partial view that loads up after some user input that needs the same functionality so I'm referencing the script again in the partial view causing the document ready function to fire again and it assigns the onclick events for my controls in the partial view. That works. Except the problem is that I'm getting two onclick event for the controls on the main page causing the event to fire twice if I click on the main page controls after the partial view is loaded. I tried just adding an .off() in the jquery loop to remove the event before it's added so that the second time it runs it would remove the first one and add a new one but the event doesn't get removed. I also tried rewriting it to use .addEventListener and .removeEventLister following the same pattern; removing before adding it, but get the same results.

If I could query for the currently attached event listeners I could easily prevent the second addition of the onclick event but my research tells there's no way to do this in javascript (though you can in chrome dev tools with getEventListeners()).

So why isn't it removing the first event when I do .off() or .removeEventListener()? Is there some kind of scoping like this script that I'm calling twice, it ends up being two instances of the script and you can't remove event listeners that were applied by another script? This is just a guess.

Any guidance would be useful, thanks.

Comment: This is a "[where is Waldo"](https://www.123sonography.com/sites/default/files/article/images/2_Waldo_Illustration.png) question without knowing the details about Waldo, what Waldo is wearing, what Waldo looks like, what gender Waldo is, etc. We can all guess until we get lucky, but I'm not sure that is the purpose of SO.  Please do your best to produce a [example].

Comment: so there's not some kind of event scoping?

Comment: @yellephen Would checking if `event.target === event.currentTarget` work for you? Events bubble, and that comparison will check if the element that triggered the event (`target`) is the same as the element you attached the event listener to (`currentTarget`). You can then call `event.stopPropagation()`; that will essentially scope the event to a specific element / target. Read up on those terms though to make sure you don't do something unexpected. Generally you don't want to "scope" events like this.

Comment: @chipit24 - the OP has created a memory leak - your suggestion exacerbates the issue.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a memory leak to me but I agree, OPs situation is difficult to diagnose and provide a meaningful answer to. I moreso blindly wrote my thoughts in response to the title vs. what was written in the body.

Comment: It seems assigning the outerHTML of the elements to themselves in the jquery loop stops the double event but I don't really like it.

Comment: @chipit24 - I re-read the novel and you are correct, no memory leak - I confounded running the script more than once and the word loop that stuck out at me. Either way, OP needs to provided debugging details.